# Sitecore ItemService API resolve .../link.aspx?_id=abc

Tags: sitecore-api, itemservice

the Sitecore ItemService API returns a field `ÌtemUrl` which contains something like this `~/link.aspx?_id=35D02976C748402A8E6F22A2827F4451&amp;_z=z`

Is it possible to turn this into a URL like `www.mypage.com/hello` using the ItemService API? I've tried calling `<server>/link.aspx?_id....` but it returns a 404.

Do I have to use the EntityServices API?

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box in Sitecore.

Filling of item properties is not configurable, it is hardcoded:

```
private static void FillProperties(ItemDataModel itemModel, Item item, string urlPrefix)
{
    item.Fields?.ReadAll();
    itemModel.Id = item.ID.Guid.ToString();
    itemModel.Name = item.Name;
    itemModel.Path = item.Paths?.Path;
    itemModel.Language = item.Language?.Name;
    itemModel.Version = ((item.Version != null) ? item.Version.Number : (-1));
    itemModel.IsLatestVersion = (item.Versions?.IsLatestVersion() ?? false);
    itemModel.ParentId = ((!ID.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ParentID)) ? item.ParentID.Guid : Guid.Empty);
    itemModel.TemplateId = ((!ID.IsNullOrEmpty(item.TemplateID)) ? item.TemplateID.Guid : Guid.Empty);
    itemModel.TemplateName = item.TemplateName;
    itemModel.Created = (((DateTimeOffset?)item.Statistics?.Created) ?? default(DateTimeOffset));
    itemModel.Updated = (((DateTimeOffset?)item.Statistics?.Updated) ?? default(DateTimeOffset));
    itemModel.Url = FormattableString.Invariant($"{urlPrefix}('{itemModel.Id}')");
    itemModel.DisplayName = item[FieldIDs.DisplayName];
}
```

What you can do:

1. Inherit your new model data factory from `ItemDataModelFactory`
2. Override `public virtual ItemDataModel GetModel(Item item, string urlPrefix)` method. It calls `FillProperties`. After filling properties, you should be able either add a new property for the link or change existing.
3. Inherit from `Sitecore.Content.Services.Controllers.ItemsController` (it is responsible for ItemService APi). Pass to constructor your new ItemDataModelFactory instead of `Sitecore.Content.Services.Items.OData.ItemDataModelFactory`
4. Register your new route

Comment: I went with using the EntityService to solve my problem. Thank you for your suggestion! It definitely helped me.